# How to add a little to URL instead of copying and pasting it all?

Tags: php, html

Ok, so I have let's say this page `http://mypage.com/index.php?id=something`. I want to have in this page the link which would go to the `http://mypage.com/index.php?id=something&sub=1`. And to do that I have to add `a href` to my index.php file like this 
`echo '<a href="index.php?id=something&sub=1">go here</a>';`. Is it possible to do this thing shorter? I mean just adding `sub=1` somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is PHP command called `http_build_url` that is specifically for your type of use case.

This is how you would use it for your example:

```
http_build_url($url_string,
    array(
        "query" => "sub=1"
    ),
    HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can do something like:

```
echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&sub=1">go here</a>'
```

In JavaScript, you could do:

```
location.search += "&sub=1";
```

But this is not really a good reason to require JavaScript.

Comment: Don't forget the obvious -- this solution works fine unless your URL has no querystring, in which case you'll have to prepend a ? instead of the &.

Answer (score 1):

In php you can get:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

That should give you the requested url, but adding `&sub=1` is risky in case the page got called without a query string because it would result in:

```
index.php&sub=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] + "&sub=1";

Comment: `PHP_SELF` is not a constant, but a string and should thus be encapsulated in quotes. Additionally, it does not contain the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the pages' URL. You can then modify that as you would any other string.

See [Predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == '' ? '?' : '&') . 'sub=1">go here</a>';
```

But sooner or later you will have to face the problem that you may "add" a parameter that is already in the query string. So I would recommend to write a function/method that handles adding/removing query parameters to a URL.